# Python check if exists in SQLite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, exists

I'm trying to check whether a variable exists in an SQLite3 db. Unfortunately I can not seem to get it to work. The airports table contains 3 colums, with ICAO as the first column.

```
if c.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM airports WHERE ICAO='EHAM')") is True:
    print("Found!")
else:
    print("Not found...")
```

The code runs without any errors, but the result is always the same (not found).

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 9):

Try this instead:

```
c.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM airports WHERE ICAO='EHAM')")

if c.fetchone():
    print("Found!")

else:
    print("Not found...")
```

Return value of `cursor.execute` is cursor (or to be more precise reference to itself) and is independent of query results. You can easily check that:

```
 >>> r = c.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM airports WHERE ICAO='EHAM')")
 >>> r is True
 False
 >>> r is False
 False
 >>> r is None
 False

 >>> r is c
 True
```

From the other hand if you call `cursor.fetchone` result tuple or None if there is no row that passes query conditions. So in your case `if c.fetchone():` would mean one of the below:

```
if (1, ):
    ...
```

or

```
if None:
    ...
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as EXISTS either returns a 0 or 1 in sqlite3. See the docs (http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html): "The EXISTS operator always evaluates to one of the integer values 0 and 1. If executing the SELECT statement specified as the right-hand operand of the EXISTS operator would return one or more rows, then the EXISTS operator evaluates to 1. If executing the SELECT would return no rows at all, then the EXISTS operator evaluates to 0. " So you can change the answer from `None` to (0,). I will edit if nobody objects in the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prepare a database to test it.

```
import sqlite3
c = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c.execute("CREATE TABLE airports (ICAO STRING, col2 STRING, col3 STRING)")
c.execute("INSERT INTO airports (ICAO, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", ('EHAM', 'value2', 'value3'))
```

Since your `SELECT 1 FROM airports WHERE ICAO = 'EHAM'` already serves the purpose of checking existence, let's use it directly, without the redundant `SELECT EXISTS()`

```
if c.execute("SELECT 1 FROM airports WHERE ICAO = 'EHAM'").fetchone():
    print("Found!")
else:
    print("Not found...")
```

the result is

```
Found!
```

Let's check a non-existent case

```
if c.execute("SELECT 1 FROM airports WHERE ICAO = 'NO-SUCH'").fetchone():
    print("Found!")
else:
    print("Not found...")
```

the result is

```
Not found...
```

If you just want to fix your code, you can try

```
if c.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM airports WHERE ICAO = 'EHAM')").fetchone() == (1,):
    print("Found!")
else:
    print("Not found...")
```

the result is

```
Found!
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer from zero323, although the code snippet is wrong, as `fetchone()` does not return True or False. It only returns 1 for True and 0 for False. (binary) The following code works without problems in Python3:

```
response = self.connection.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM invoices WHERE id=?)", (self.id, ))
fetched = response.fetchone()[0]
if fetched == 1:
    print("Exist")
else:
    print("Does not exist")
```