# iterating over an sql column to append to a python list

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm making a user/login type thing in python and need to iterate over a certain column in an sql database to append to a python list so that a new user cannot have a username already taken in my database. I have no clue where to start but here is what I've have

```
import sqlite3
users = sqlite3.connect('D:\lel.db')
uquery = users.cursor()
name_list=[]
def createtable():
uquery.execute('''CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS users (userforename text, usersurname text,username text,password text,userscore,userdifficulty text)''')

def adduserintotable(userforename, usersurname, username, password,userscore,userdifficulty,uquery):
uquery.execute('''INSERT INTO users (userforename,usersurname,username,password,userscore,userdifficulty)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)''', (userforename, usersurname, username, password,  userscore,userdifficulty))
users.commit()




def newuser():
uquery = users.cursor()
userforename = (str(input("What is your forename? ")))
usersurname = (str(input("What is your Surname? ")))
username = (str(input("whats your username ")))
password = (input("What is your passcode? "))
userscore = (0)
userdifficulty = ("")
diffchosen = False
#name_list=SELECT username FROM users
#for row in users.execute("name_list"):
 #  print (row)
#print(name_list)
while diffchosen ==  False:
     difficulties = ["easy","medium","hard"]
     for difficulty in difficulties:
        print (difficulty)
     print ("Choose a difficulty ")
     while userdifficulty != "easy" and userdifficulty != "medium" and userdifficulty != "hard":
        try:
           userdifficulty = str(input("Please insert a valid difficulty "))
        except:
           print ("you inputted an incorrect difficulty")
     diffchosen = True
adduserintotable(userforename, usersurname, username, password, userscore,userdifficulty,uquery)
users.commit()
createtable()
newuser()
```

PS I already have all the data in the database and how a user an enter their own

Thanks :D

Comment: Why retrieve all the users and iterate over them to check for collisions?  Just query the database to see if the chosen username already exists.

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817699/python-check-if-exists-in-sqlite3

Comment: Thanks, i've including this guys code in my program, changing it to suit of course