# SELECT EXISTS to check if row exists in another table

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to use `SELECT EXISTS` to find any matching row based on the email column. At first I through it was working but then I noticed it would give me the same result no matter what I do.

Here is the code:

```
def insert():
    time.sleep(5)
    email = "fakeemailgunicornalltestf@fakemail.com"
    company = "Conglomo"
    typeemail = "whitelist"
    try:    
        connecttosql = sqlite3.connect('database/spamdatabase.db')
        connectioncursor = connecttosql.cursor()

        connectioncursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM loggedemails WHERE email = ?)", (email,))
        # print(connectioncursor.fetchone())
        if connectioncursor.fetchone():
            alreadyprocessed = "This has been already processed. This is was an error you may want to reverse this action. (Feature coming soon)"
            print(alreadyprocessed)
            return alreadyprocessed
        else:            
            sql_insertval = """INSERT INTO heldforreview (email, company, type)
                                VALUES(?,?,?)
                                CHECK ;"""
            sowreqeust = (email,company,typeemail)
            connectioncursor.execute(sql_insertval, sowreqeust)
            connecttosql.commit() 
            insert.result = "SUCCESS"

    except Exception as Argument:
        print("Email is added to database error: "+str(Argument))
        insert.result = "FAILED"
        print(insert.result)
        return insert.result
    print(insert.result)
    return insert.result
insert()
```

The code above is suppose to check the `loggedemails` column to see if `fakeemailgunicornalltestf@fakemail.com` has already been added. However it says its been already added even though it hasn't been added yet purposely.

Any suggestions?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: That part of the code was a mess up and shouldn't have been posted here. I was just testing a bunch of things to get it to work. The code has been updated. I got the SELECT EXISTS idea from this stack overflow post: I got the idea from this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18817754 Sorry for the confusion. @khelwood

Comment: I think you should print `fetchone()` and see what it is returning. If it returns a nonempty tuple, then `if connectioncursor.fetchone():` will succeed: that doesn't mean that it found the email in your database.

Comment: when I tried `print(connectioncursor.fetchone())` it gave me a result of `(0,)` Should I try `if connectioncursor.fetchone()=="(1,)":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `SELECT EXISTS` query finds the row you're looking for, then `fetchone` will return a tuple containing 1 (meaning true).

If it does not find the row, then `fetchone` will return a tuple containing 0 (meaning false).

In either case `if connectioncursor.fetchone():` will succeed, because a nonempty tuple is truthy, whatever it contains.

You can fix it by changing your condition to the following:

```py
if connectioncursor.fetchone()[0]:
```

or

```py
if connectioncursor.fetchone()==(1,):
```

Comment: `if connectioncursor.fetchone()[0]:` totally worked! Thanks for helping me out with that.